# Create a Databricks job using Talend Open Studio

Tags: azure-databricks, talend

Can I create a Databricks job using Talend Open Studio then export and register the exported job in the Databricks workflow and execute it?

How can I create Databricks job using Talend Open Studio?
How can I run Databricks job exported by Talend Open Studio in Azure Databricks Workflows?

Answer (score 0):

Download the JAR file from the Talend.

Make sure You have the JDK 11 installed in the databricks  cluster.
If you dont have the latest JDK. add this in your envinorment
**JNAME=zulu11-ca-amd64**

[image]

Create a job in databricks Cluster.

[image]

In the next page create the task name, select the path to notebook and your cluster on which it needs to be run.
Then hit on create.

Type = JAR
Main class= Your main class

[image]

Add Your Jar Here.
Then click on create.
And Start running the JOB.
Then you will get as below

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the way you create a sample databrick jobs in the Talend Open Studio (For Big Data) and how can you export it as JAR file ? Thanks